# HTML Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Trying to retrieve current URL from the tab. The goal is to be able to click on this extension and it automatically pulls the search information for the domain of the current chrome table. trying to use this search url to pull whatever "www.apple.com" tab window url is currently being visited into the extension to get company information.

Heres what I have: 
popup.html

```
    <head>

        <title>
            Chrome Extension
        </title>

        <script src="offline.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <iframe src="https://www.owler.com/iaApp/browsecompanyprofiles.htm?searchTerm=$activeTab” oncontextmenu="return false;">
            ERROR, can't load content
        </iframe>

    <script>
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(arrayOfTabs) {
     var activeTab = arrayOfTabs[0];
     var activeTabId = activeTab.id;
  });
function getCookie(cname) 
    {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');

        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) 
        {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
        {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }

    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
    {
    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
}
return "";
}

if(getCookie('hostinger')) {
document.cookie = 'hostinger=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';location.reload();
}
var notification = document.getElementsByClassName('notice notice-success is-dismissible');
if(notification.length > 0) {
notification = notification[0];
notification.setAttribute('style', "padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 5px; background-image: url(https://cdn.rawgit.com/hostinger/banners/master/hostinger-bf-bg.jpg); background-size: cover; background-position: bottom right; background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #ffffff;");var h1Tag = notification.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];h1Tag.setAttribute('style', "color:#f15f5f;font-weight:700;");h1Tag.innerHTML = "Get 90% Discount for Premium Web Hosting";var link = notification.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].getElementsByTagName('A')[0];link.setAttribute('style', "color:#f15f5f");var list = notification.getElementsByTagName("UL")[0];var listElements = list.getElementsByTagName("LI");for (var i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {listElements[i].setAttribute('style', "color:#ffffff");}}

        <iframe src="https://www.owler.com/iaApp/browsecompanyprofiles.htm?searchTerm=$activeTab” oncontextmenu="return false;">
            ERROR, can't load content
        </iframe>
</script></body>

</html>

<style>

html, body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

iframe{
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    border: none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: u want the url of current active tab or all the open tabs?

Comment: just the current active tab within the window

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` will give you the url of the current tab

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work within my code. I get an error each time. I think it has to do with the iframe code.

Comment: I'd want it to use "https://www.owler.com/iaApp/browsecompanyprofiles.htm?searchTerm=" + ACTIVETAB

Comment: I've tried that but within the iframe code, it doesn't work.

Comment: can u try window.top.location.href

Comment: I'm new to this. Where would I put that within my code?

Comment: u said "window.location.href doesn't work with iframe src" ; wherever u tried that, try "window.top.location.href "; cant agree anything; just a hunch

Comment: iframe src doesn't allow me to pass in a variable. Only a quoted string.